# ¿Tienen nombre concreto los dedos intermedios de los pies?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, sustantivos, palabras-raras, cuerpo-humano

Los [dedos](https://dle.rae.es/dedo) de la mano tienen al menos una designación específica:

- Pulgar
- Índice
- Corazón
- Anular
- Meñique

En el caso del pie parece que solo tienen una designación específica los dos extremos: gordo y meñique.

¿Hay algún nombre específico para los tres dedos centrales del pie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedo) la respuesta es no.

> A diferencia de lo que sucede con la mano, en el pie, en lugar de usar un nombre diferente para cada dedo, en el ámbito científico es habitual referirse a ellos por el número que ocupan, y empiezan a contarse desde la parte de dentro. Por ejemplo, el dedo gordo es el «primer dedo del pie», el siguiente el «segundo dedo del pie», y así sucesivamente.
>
> Solo algunos dedos del pie tienen un nombre específico equivalente al nombre correspondiente del dedo de la mano: dedo gordo3 (Hallux, dedo pulgar​), dedo meñique​ (dedo auricular).6